# Chrome addon to stop "Page(s) Unresponsive" message

Tags: chrome

Whenever there are too many tabs opened, Chrome will show a "[Page(s) Unresponsive](https://superuser.com/q/426516/78897)" message:

[image: Page(s) Unresponsive: The following page(s) have become unresponsive. You can wait for them to become responsive or kill them.]

Optional informative rant:

> Now, I know that the tabs'll eventually respond and thus I do not wish
>   to kill the pages. I would rather let them load while I'm working on
>   other things on the other tabs.
>
> However, the popup would reappear after [**every** couple of
>   seconds](https://superuser.com/q/843568/78897).
>
> This is severely annoying not just because it's a **popup**, —I was
>   about to write a 5-page long rant on why popups are bad, but basically
>   it boils down to creating unnecessary context switches and stealing
>   keyboard presses— but it's a never-ending series of center-screen
>   popups, one after another.

Is there a Chrome addon to do **any** of these? :

- 'Wait' and do not ask again.
- 'Wait' and do not ask for the next *x* minutes/hours.
- Don't even ask, just 'Wait'.
- Stop the message from appearing on the center-screen as a popup. (Make it behave more like simple notifications.)

Comment: does this work to disable it?? http://superuser.com/questions/849475/can-i-turn-off-chromes-pages-unresponsive-dialog

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, How would we **verify** that?

Comment: No real way to verify it works - just wait and see :) If you're finding these are pretty common, wait a week or so and see if they've stopped coming. Sorry - no real way I can think of!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no addon which stopping “Page(s) Unresponsive” message, because this issue is usually related when your operating system is busy with processing too many tabs. Although you can try running your Chrome with [`--disable-hang-monitor` parameter](https://superuser.com/q/849475/87805).

Since it's not clear how many tabs you mean by 'too many tabs opened', but I had similar issues when having hundreds of tabs opened for each profile (in *People*), which could sometimes reach thousands. This is related to heavy websites which are using constantly processing power for animations (e.g. adverts, gif, flash), JS scripts, etc.

To deal with such issues in general, these addons can be helpful:

- [The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg) (see: [GitHub](https://github.com/deanoemcke/thegreatsuspender)) extension

  This great extension auto-suspends tabs that have not been used for a while by freeing up memory, resources and CPU that the tab was consuming. So you could open huge amount of tabs, and their background processing would be stopped after certain time of inactivity.
- [Tab Dupectomy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-dupectomy/nkkedbpcfdogedipgdhgeknjdphaplbk) - get rid of duplicated tabs with one click.
- [OneTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall) - save up to 95% memory and reduce tab clutter by converting all tabs into a list.
- [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/) - block annoying ads or user-defined content which increases browser performance and response rate.
- [Flashcontrol](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flashcontrol/mfidmkgnfgnkihnjeklbekckimkipmoe) - by default blocks loading of flash content until you allow it.
- [Ghostery](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghostery/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij) - significantly speed up your browsing by blocking offending tracker scripts.
- check [10 Ad Blocking Extensions Tested for Best Performance](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/10-ad-blocking-extensions-tested-for-best-performance/) for more.

Alternatively use different browser which can deal with many tabs at the same time, see: [Web-browser for heavy browsing, alternative to Chrome](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/31811/3474).