# Web-browser for heavy browsing, alternative to Chrome

Tags: osx, web-browser

I'm heavy web user which requires a lot of tabs being opened during my everyday work (>=50-200 tabs). I'm using Google Chrome browser for couple of years and become very slow and an overkill for my operating system  on everyday basis (OS X, El Capitan).

I'm already using minimum amount of extensions, such as [OneTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall) (for saving non-used tabs), [Tab Dupectomy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nkkedbpcfdogedipgdhgeknjdphaplbk) (to remove duplicates) and [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/) (for blocking animated ads), blocking flash, and everything else to reduce the memory and CPU processing of multiple tabs. However still every often my system freezes because of Chrome, so I have to kill some background tabs which taking the most resources and freezing my system, but this is only the workaround. Most of the time closing or opening new tab is taking several seconds to complete. I've reported several bugs against Chrome, but it's pointless work (as most of the reports are without resolution for years) and it's just too heavy to use in general (as the feature list is growing) and it's just broken on so many levels.

[image: Chrome web-browser performance issues - high CPU usage - screenshot - iStat Menus]]
[image: Chrome web-browser performance issues - high CPU usage - screenshot - iStat Menus]]

Note: I've 2.3GHz Intel Core i7 (4 cores) with 16GB of RAM with NVIDIA GeForce, so I don't think my hardware is the issue.

---

Based on above, I'm forced to change my browser to achieve some better performance during heavy browsing.

It should have the following features:

- HTML5 support,
- tab support,
- keyboard shortcut support,
- quicker than Chrome in terms of simultaneous opened tabs (50-200)

Nice to have:

- open source,
- community support,
- both Linux & Unix support,
- plugin support (to block flash and animated ads),
- different profile support (e.g. switching cookies for the same pages, like *People* in *Chrome*),
- ability to disable background processing (for tabs not being in use).

Budget: ideally free, but I'm consider to pay reasonable amount for the better quality.

Comment: Don't you think there is a more efficient way of doing what you need without using a browser? Like a Python script or something. 200 tabs seems unnecessary.

Comment: I'm using Python when downloading things, but when I'm browsing pages I'm using web-browser. I'm tired of saving everything temporary into bookmarks, desktop, files, and thinking everything is fine, only because the web-browser can't handle the amount of tabs opened. It's like flaw by design, processing all the tabs at once even those which are minimized or not used at all. So I hope somebody came up with some better solution.

Comment: What other mainstream browsers have you tried? Firefox, Safari, Opera?

Comment: @kenorb A human can't browse 50-200 pages at once. You can make scripts to send you an e-mail or warn you once something changes on a website so you open it only when you know there's something important there. Of course you could get a Intel Xeon processor which has many cores that can process tabs, but it is very expensive. I think that you should try Firefox because I see people saying they have up to 700 tabs open without crashing. I don't know if that's true, but Firefox is a lot better than Chrome when handling tabs.

Comment: @CalvT I've at least 7 web-browsers installed: Chrome, Firefox, Opera (some turbo mode, but it doesn't support HTTPS), Safari, Epic, Vivaldi, Tor. I don't cross them out, but some kind of prove that something works faster with 200 simultaneous tabs would be great.

Comment: @Janekmuric I'm using Google Alerts also, I've reached 1000 limit as well as IFTTT, but then I end up with thousands of e-mails every day. But it's about just web-browsing. I was using Firefox before I tried Chrome, every time when I run it, it's checking for the updates, so till it finishes, I'm already browsing using different web-browser. As far as I remember It was crashing quiet often. I may try again. I'm considering Mac Pro (Xeon), but it's quiet expensive, maybe at the end of year I'll buy it, currently I'm looking for some workarounds if any.

Comment: @kenorb if your problem is that Chrome has become to feature heavy, what about installing an earlier version of Chromium? That way it wont auto update to the latest version.

Comment: @Janekmuric E.g. when reading some new notifications, usually I'm opening them in separate tabs, so I can read them all by using close-and-next method (20-50 tabs). Same with e-mail. Then another 20-50 tabs from work (JIRA/Confluence, or whatever). Then some Stack.Ex notifications which take another 20 tabs, then I'm gooling smth, so usually opening first 10 pages, then I'm shopping something - another 20 tabs, reading - 20 tabs, and so on. End of day, As I'm got distracted, end of day I end up with 300 tabs of unfinished things to complete. Of course I'm closing the one which I've finished.

Comment: @CalvT Probably this would be too outdated and buggy, but I could try (probably better to use some lightweight fork, like [Midori](http://midori-browser.org/download/), but it is not OS X compatible). I've seen some people doing that (downgrading Chrome), because they didn't like some changes. I don't like either, like publishing all my passwords in the [cloud](https://passwords.google.com/) without even asking me. Before web was [very simple](http://motherfuckingwebsite.com/), now every tab consumes large amount of resources and CPU.

Comment: Also I'm considering running Chrome (or different compatible browser) under X virtual framebuffer (headlessly), and run it on the dedicated server or on separate compute stick (at least I don't have to hear the sound of fans going crazy). Then use X11 forwarding via SSH. If that will work fine, I'll post the potential answer.

Comment: @kenorb I don't think it would be buggy because after all the early versions of chrome are the ones that won almost half the users in the world... I don't think it could of done that if it was buggy! Also it has supported HTML5 for a long time, so if you chose say Chrome 29 I doubt you'd run into many problems.

Comment: Ideally we need a browser that isn't using tabs, but is using "to read" lists, which are sorted based on the page they are linked to. They ideally would download the page while there is network connectivity but not render them until the user is ready to view the page, thereby not using up any CPU or memory until viewed.

I honestly don't know why there aren't more (or any) web browsers around that do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the [Brave browser](https://brave.com/) which promises [faster Web](https://brave.com/index.html#faster) by banishing intrusive ads, stripping away everything but the real content.

Background: Brendan Eich, who invented JavaScript and co-founded Mozilla, after resigning as Mozilla's chief executive is now heading a new startup called Brave Software that promises to make the Internet safer and faster when the company publicly launches it in early 2016.<sup>[cnet](http://www.cnet.com/news/mystery-startup-from-ex-mozilla-ceo-aims-to-go-where-tech-titans-wont/)</sup> The project has also support from a few ex-Mozilla engineers who are working on on it. See: [ycombinator news](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10940970).

On its website we can read:

> Up to a whopping 60% of page load time is caused by the underlying ad technology that loads 
>   into various places each time you hit a page on your favorite news site.
>   And 20% of this is time spent on loading things that are trying to learn more about you.

Here is example news page data and load time with tracking allowed and normal ads allowed against same page data and load time with tracking blocked and normal ads blocked:

[image: Brave browser - Example news page data and load time with tracking allowed and normal ads allowed - loading times]

It has very minimalistic features with class leading speed, security and protection which gives users control over their personal data by blocking ad trackers and third party cookies. For example on mobile devices the web page load time speedups is massive (see: [Brave Browser iOS Speed Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHWf6hRV-GM)).

The large amount of tabs can be organised by tab pages, where maximum tabs can be separated per each page.

The desktop browser is a cross-platform desktop application with support for most of major operating systems created with a fork of Github's [Electron framework](https://github.com/brave/electron) that is itself based on [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/).

You may compare the JS speed between the browsers using [speed-battle browser test](http://www.speed-battle.com/). I had better results in terms of overall score with Brave than with Chrome on Macbook Pro.

Homepage: [Brave.com](https://brave.com/)

License: [Mozilla Public License](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/blob/master/LICENSE.txt)

Source code at GitHub: https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop

---

Alternative web-browsers (which can be quicker than Chrome), are:

- [Epic](https://www.epicbrowser.com/) (privacy browser)

  It takes similar approach to Brave by blocking tracking scripts and ads which loads webpages as much as 25% faster than other browsers.
- [Opera](http://www.opera.com/) and its [Turbo mode](http://www.opera.com/turbo)

  Using turbo mode (HTTP only) speed up slow connections and load pages faster since Opera's servers identifies pieces of the page that can be compressed and sends back these smaller-sized pieces to your computer, reducing volume of data transferred by up to 80%.

  > The web content your device receives to a fraction of its original size. You get all the videos, photos and text that you normally would, but you eat up less data and load pages faster.
- [Maxthon Cloud Browser](http://www.maxthon.com/?lang#product)

  It's using less memory than Firefox, Chrome or Opera.<sup>[softwareinsider](http://web-browsers.softwareinsider.com/)</sup>

  - > Lightning fast speed – Maxthon Cloud renders webpage using its optimized web engine that loads webpages and runs applications faster than any other browsers;
  - > Superior Speed Users can enjoy faster speed in loading webpage and running applications.
- [Midori](http://midori-browser.org/) (based on WebKit), support for Windows & Linux, but not OS X

  > Midori is blazing fast, utilizing the latest web technologies and a small, but dexterous array of extensions provide all the essential features.

---

On the other hand, Chrome could be not so bad, if properly tweaked. See this for further details: [Chrome addon to stop "Page(s) Unresponsive" message](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/20108/3474).

Comment: to bad they've dumbed down ghostery :\

Comment: I use [Lazy Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazy-tabs/aabgbgciohhaogajcnacpgilhmacdahc?hl=en) to not wait up to half an hour while hundreds of tabs load. Does OneTab handle that scenario as well?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman OneTab works differently. It's exporting opened tabs into a flat list, so you can re-open them in most convenient time later on without having a lot of tabs having opened.

Comment: So OneTab supports hundreds of tabs and multiple sessions like [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en), without manual saving?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Yes, like multiple session, for example as shown in [here](http://core0.staticworld.net/images/article/2013/03/onetab-for-chrome-100030551-orig.jpg).